# VSTS task based on phase from another task

Tags: azure-devops

When using `Build and Release`, it currently doesn't seem to be possible to link or import a phase from another task (i couldn't find any helpful information in the documentation).
I have specified a task (let's call it `build task`, where i have specified a phase (`build phase`) to build my solution (and some other phases like publishing symbols etc.).
So my question is: is it possible to reference to `build phase` from `build task` (or import `build phase`, so that the steps of this phase are cloned into this phase in case i want to prevent later changes in the linked phase to influence the phase in the new task).
Like link (or import) `build phase` from `build task` into current task in phase `preparation phase`?

Comment: It is not that clear what you ask: Phase and Task have precise meaning in VSTS (A phase is a series of tasks that run sequentially on the same target. A task is the building block for defining automation in a build definition, or in an environment of a release definition.). To me "I have specified a task, where i have specified a phase" makes no sense. Your question is about reuse of code or how to flow data from one step to another?

Comment: Do you solve this issue with Task group?

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t such feature in VSTS build/release.

There is he Task Groups feature that you can encapsulate a sequence of tasks, more information, you can refer to: [Task groups for builds and releases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/library/task-groups?view=vsts)